# Vectorizing or for loop or apply function?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 6 columns. Column 1 holds dates, column 2 individuals and column 3 to 6 the are used for a calcuation.

```
Date <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3)
Ind <- c("a","a","a","b","c","c")
C <- c(5, 6, 5, 7, 8, 8)
D <- c(8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9)
E <- c(8, 9, 11, 10, 9, 7)
F <- c(5, 6, 8, 5, 7, 4)

df <- data.frame(Date, Ind, C, D, E, F)
```

I want to perform a calculation (like (C-E)+(D-F) (in real life those are coordinates and I'm calculating distances, but that's not where my problem is right now).

I want to perform the calculations, stored in a new column (G), with a 1 day difference between where I use the value of column C and E from day 1, and the values of column E and F from day+1 for the same individual.

I'm not sure if I should use a loop or an apply function. This is what I've tried so far, a vectorized operation and subsetting, based on this thread: [Loop over rows of dataframe applying function with if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518456/loop-over-rows-of-dataframe-applying-function-with-if-statement)

```
df$G <- NA

df[!(df$Date ==(df$Date+1)), "G"] <- ((C-E)+(D-F))
```

This works, but it does the calculations on the coordinates from the same row (C, D, E, F all from same row). I realize why it does this, as I don't state from which row to take the coordinates. C and D need to be taken from row where Date = Date, and E and F from row where Date = (Date+1). 
I realize it, but I can't get my head around it how to do that.

Continue this route? Do it in a for loop? Using apply function?

Comment: Ind a has two rows for Date 1. What would you like to do?

Comment: Distances are usually L1: `abs(C-D)+ abs(E-F)` or L2: `(C-D)^2 + (E-F)^2`, i.e always positive.

Comment: @egilio Your description is a bit confusing.  Could you show  the expected output for this example data.

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` package provides very nice `lag` and `lead` functions.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(G = C + D + lead(E,1) + lead(F,1))
  Date Ind C D  E F  G
1    1   a 5 8  8 5 28
2    1   a 6 8  9 6 33
3    2   a 5 9 11 8 29
4    2   b 7 9 10 5 32
5    2   c 8 9  9 7 28
6    3   c 8 9  7 4 NA
```

G is `NA` for the last row because there is no *next* Date value.

### Edit:

As others have mentioned, it looks like your example data has two Dates for `Ind==a`. You may want to be careful doing lead/lag in that situation.

If it makes sense to do so, you could aggregate them first, before doing lead/lag.

```
df %>% group_by(Date,Ind) %>% 
  summarise(C=mean(C),D=mean(D),E=mean(E),F=mean(F)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(G = C + D + lead(E,1) + lead(F,1))
```

Which produces:

```
  Date Ind   C D    E   F    G
1    1   a 5.5 8  8.5 5.5 32.5
2    2   a 5.0 9 11.0 8.0 29.0
3    2   b 7.0 9 10.0 5.0 32.0
4    2   c 8.0 9  9.0 7.0 28.0
5    3   c 8.0 9  7.0 4.0   NA
```

Comment: The `Date` column is same for `3:5` and `1:2` rows.  Also, it seems to be grouped by `Ind`.  So, I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm assuming that that wasn't an intended feature of the data as the OP didn't mention how that would be handled.

Comment: I was looking at OP's code `df$Date ==(df$Date+1)`.  May be you are right, but the example and description is confusing.